# Why does Windows keep prompting for a sign in?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I'm using Windows 10 x64 Enterprise and find I keep getting prompted during regular use of windows to sign in to something.

I'm not sure which application is doing this, or how to stop it. Cancelling or entering my credentials doesn't seem to do anything/alter my experience.

I've come across a few threads on MSDN forums about this specifically associated with Outlook, however I don't have Outlook installed as I just use Gmail.

Does anyone know how I might stop this, or at least track down which program is initiating the sign in prompt?

[image]

Comment: Windows 10 Enterprise suggests you are connected to a corporate network.  Is that the case?

Comment: Disable HomeGroup sharing (turn Password protected sharing OFF). Disable "Always prompt for login credentials" setting in Outlook settings. Remove all Outlook-related credentials from Windows credentials.

Comment: @Ramhound I am plugged in via Ethernet but I don't login to the network (it's filtered by MAC address) and my windows credentials are just local to this machine (no active directory). Noticed actually that the Explorer icon turns orange so I think that's the trigger for some reason.

Comment: @Akina I don't have Outlook installed

Comment: It doesn't matter. The settings may exist nevertheless. Especially if you use Microsoft account, not local one...

Comment: @Akina I can't find any homegroup settings to disable (service certainly doesn't exist). Obviously as I have no outlook I can't change the always prompt, also checked and there were no outlook credentials in the manager.

Comment: Look at the recommendations in [this link](https://windowsreport.com/windows-security-pop-up-windows-10/), for example.

Comment: @Ian - Your comment does not answer my question.  Let me ask my question another way, that will answer my question, are you using a personal or company computer?  Windows 10 Enterprise can only activate with a KMS, this is not something you typically find or even implent, outside of the corporate setting.

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry if I mis-understood. Yes it's a company computer.

Comment: @Ian - Have you asked your IT Administrator about the prompt?  This might be expected, and is an indication your system is not properly configured, or the configuration at least incomplete.

Comment: @Ramhound no not yet, as it's a machine I basically setup myself. But that might be the next step.

Comment: You may use Process Explorer to track the process that is issuing the message. Drag the binoculars icon over the message.